# How to combine two variable as one foreach?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php foreach($query as $q){?>
  <?php foreach($results as $r){?> 
    <div style="overflow:auto"> 
      <div class="main">
        <div class="column">         
          <p class="created_by">created by: <?php echo $q['username']; ?> at <?php echo $q['Date']; ?></p>
          <a href="../../../article/article/view.php?id=<?php echo $q['id']?>">
            <h3 class="title-box"><?php echo $r['title']; ?></h3>
          </a>
          <h6 class="content-box"><?php echo substr($r['content'],0,100); ?></h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

the above code is my php code.

my problem: when i echo the result ,it show the same result multiple time .

**image of my problem:**
[image: 1]

what i want it to be: all the echo data only show one time.

what i had try :i try to search in google for a lot times and combine using a lot ways but i failed.For exmple ,using array_merge and more

Comment: _it show the same result multiple time_ maybe because is inside 2 `foreach` loops??

Comment: yes it is,can you help me with it?

Comment: If the arrays contain related data and are coming from a relational database, this could be elegantly solved with a SQL JOIN.

Comment: No basically it just a search form this is the page which echo the result.In my opinioni think that the multiple result is cause by two foreach in my code.But whaat if i can combine both of the foreach in one? Thank you.

Comment: And where does the results data come from ? If there's no SQL involved and there's no common keys between the 2 arrays, I'd use `array_map('array_merge', $query, $results)`.

Comment: can you let me know more specific what i need list out sorry for the disturb.

Comment: I think you need to be clear about what is in $query and what are in $results. My guess is that $query is listing modifications or revisions of the articles in $results. If so, you'd want to swap the positions of the two for loops, and echo the article ($r) things within the outer loop but not the inner.